# Devise: edit_password_url in password reset email is sending users to url/api/v1/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my rails app and Devise set up to use a JSON API to do user registration and login. A side effect is that `edit_password_url` in the password reset email is accidentally sending users to:

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/v1/password/edit?reset_password_token=ZzyPCgmspN2964ENUkSS
```

when it shouldn't have `api/v1/`, and should send them to:

```
http://localhost:3000/password/edit?reset_password_token=ZzyPCgmspN2964ENUkSS
```

I've been looking, but can't figure out where to fix this.

I've created the following:

```
Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

and

```
Api::V1::RegistrationsController < RegistrationsController
```

I have a regular RegistrationsController that inherits from devise, but not a regular SessionsController, so I just inherit straight from devise there.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

`routes.rb`

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
      devise_for :users, :path => '', path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
                                      controllers: {  omniauth_callbacks: "authentications", registrations: "registrations"}
    end
  end

devise_for :users, :path => '', path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
                                  controllers: {  omniauth_callbacks: "authentications", registrations: "registrations"}

  resources :users
```

EDIT 2: `rake routes` output

```
        new_api_v1_user_session GET      /api/v1/login(.:format)                                    api/v1/sessions#new {:format=>"json"}
            api_v1_user_session POST     /api/v1/login(.:format)                                    api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>"json"}
    destroy_api_v1_user_session DELETE   /api/v1/logout(.:format)                                   api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>"json"}
 api_v1_user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /auth/:provider(.:format)                                  authentications#passthru {:provider=>/twitter|facebook/, :format=>"json"}
  api_v1_user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /auth/:action/callback(.:format)                           authentications#(?-mix:twitter|facebook) {:format=>"json"}
           api_v1_user_password POST     /api/v1/password(.:format)                                 api/v1/passwords#create {:format=>"json"}
       new_api_v1_user_password GET      /api/v1/password/new(.:format)                             api/v1/passwords#new {:format=>"json"}
      edit_api_v1_user_password GET      /api/v1/password/edit(.:format)                            api/v1/passwords#edit {:format=>"json"}
                                PUT      /api/v1/password(.:format)                                 api/v1/passwords#update {:format=>"json"}
cancel_api_v1_user_registration GET      /api/v1/cancel(.:format)                                   registrations#cancel {:format=>"json"}
       api_v1_user_registration POST     /api/v1(.:format)                                          registrations#create {:format=>"json"}
   new_api_v1_user_registration GET      /api/v1/sign_up(.:format)                                  registrations#new {:format=>"json"}
  edit_api_v1_user_registration GET      /api/v1/edit(.:format)                                     registrations#edit {:format=>"json"}
                                PUT      /api/v1(.:format)                                          registrations#update {:format=>"json"}
                                DELETE   /api/v1(.:format)                                          registrations#destroy {:format=>"json"}
                       sessions GET      /sessions(.:format)                                        sessions#index
                                POST     /sessions(.:format)                                        sessions#create
                    new_session GET      /sessions/new(.:format)                                    sessions#new
                   edit_session GET      /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                               sessions#edit
                        session GET      /sessions/:id(.:format)                                    sessions#show
                                PUT      /sessions/:id(.:format)                                    sessions#update
                                DELETE   /sessions/:id(.:format)                                    sessions#destroy
                authentications GET      /authentications(.:format)                                 authentications#index
                                POST     /authentications(.:format)                                 authentications#create
             new_authentication GET      /authentications/new(.:format)                             authentications#new
            edit_authentication GET      /authentications/:id/edit(.:format)                        authentications#edit
                 authentication GET      /authentications/:id(.:format)                             authentications#show
                                PUT      /authentications/:id(.:format)                             authentications#update
                                DELETE   /authentications/:id(.:format)                             authentications#destroy

               new_user_session GET      /login(.:format)                                           devise/sessions#new
                   user_session POST     /login(.:format)                                           devise/sessions#create
           destroy_user_session DELETE   /logout(.:format)                                          devise/sessions#destroy
        user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /auth/:provider(.:format)                                  authentications#passthru {:provider=>/twitter|facebook/}
         user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /auth/:action/callback(.:format)                           authentications#(?-mix:twitter|facebook)
                  user_password POST     /password(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#create
              new_user_password GET      /password/new(.:format)                                    devise/passwords#new
             edit_user_password GET      /password/edit(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#edit
                                PUT      /password(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET      /cancel(.:format)                                          registrations#cancel
              user_registration POST     /                                                          registrations#create
          new_user_registration GET      /sign_up(.:format)                                         registrations#new
         edit_user_registration GET      /edit(.:format)                                            registrations#edit
                                PUT      /                                                          registrations#update
                                DELETE   /                                                          registrations#destroy
```

EDIT 3:

So I've been testing some thing out, and in the devise email template, the path `edit_password_url` is there, and works to generate the above wrong url, but when I do `rake routes`, only `edit_user_password_url` exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Devise Controller URL Helpers doc (found [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers)), I would've used:

`edit_password_path(:user)` which translates to `edit_user_password_path`. `path` seems to be interchangeable with `url`.

I'm not 100% certain but this [line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7c8f636b98810c21c339df484258c0b1446c0d43/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb#L50) defines a method called `edit_password_path` whereas this [line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7c8f636b98810c21c339df484258c0b1446c0d43/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb#L50) creates a route in the Devise context...

Comment: I have the same problem, but i cant figure out how to use this.. is there any chance i can get an advice

Answer (score 2):

According to the routes that are generated you should try this. In my case its working fine. Try this:

```
edit_user_password_url(reset_password_token: @token)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your `routes.rb` but I am guessing you want `/password/edit` to route to 'Api/V1/RegistrationsController' without `api/v1/` in URL?

If yes, then you need to use `module` option of routing DSL. like this:

```
scope module: 'api/v1/' do
  resources :sessions, :registrations
end
```

Ofcourse you need to integrate the above in `devise_for` call. I am not a devise expert, I am guessing, you will need to use `devise_scope` instead of `scope` like this:

```
devise_scope module: 'api/v1/' do
  resources :sessions, :registrations
end
```

Note: If the above doesn't work. Post back with your `routes.rb`. We will help you fix it

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just posted my routes. Let me know if you need any more of it. I'll also post the relevant output from `rake routes`

Comment: Adding the `devise_scope` didn't fix the output and caused a routing error after sending the email: `uninitialized constant SessionsController`

Comment: Just posted my routes. Let me know if you need anything else. I don't  understand why this is happening, since I seem to have a regular `edit_user_password` and an `edit_api_v1_user_password`

Answer (score 0):

So, strangely, I needed to change the path in the devise mailer template. I changed it from `edit_password_url` which worked to generate a url, but didn't show up in my `rake routes` output, to `edit_user_password_url` which I found in my `rake routes` output.

I would love to know why `edit_password_url` worked even though it doesn't show up in the `rake routes` output, and am more than happy to give assign the correct answer to someone who can explain what is going on to me.