# Pull out specific view on devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm applying a design for a Rails app, I usually works on PHP, anyway, I'm doing the reset password modifications the problem is I have the views for reset password, but not the email.

I know there is a `generate devise:views` which pull up even the email, the problem when I do this is this "damage" the current customizations in some part already done in this app by other programmer.

How can I pull up just the reset instructions email view on devise, so I can edit it?

Thanks.. I guess you can be more specific when you generate views of devise using

```
generate devise:views
```

Even more specific than

```
generate devise:views users
```

Also in the email the link is directed to localhost, for this issue I found this [Devise: edit_password_url in password reset email is sending users to url/api/v1/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259567/devise-edit-password-url-in-password-reset-email-is-sending-users-to-url-api-v1)

The problem is I can't make that work in my routes.rb which is here

```
Consult::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  scope "/admin" do
    resources :users, :controller => 'admin/users'
  end

  resources :players
  resources :player_steps
  resources :coach_steps
  resources :candidates
  resource  :payment_notifications, :only => :show
  #match 'candidates' => 'candidates#index'

  match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  #root :to => "devise/sessions#new"

  get 'user_type', to: 'home#user_type', as: :choose

  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

How in the name of rails can I make this work so that I can finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has some helpers that can come in useful when you do something wrong, such as

```
rails generate model Fish
rails g controller Fishes
```

You can also apply this to destroying the action task if you need too

```
rails destroy model Fish
rails destroy controller Fishes
```

You can apply this to anything with rails at the front so:

```
rails generate devise:views
rails destroy devise:views
```

Comment: Thanks dude!, The first i tried was "generate devise:views" but this do screw my app , then i tried "generate devise:views devise" and this is working great so far the views are in the same folder i need, and i havet found any problem (yet).

Comment: HOw will be the comment to generate for example just the "mailers" that devise generate.

Comment: I'm not to sure but you must remember that devise is an application itself so that all the files are hidden in the application, when you run generate it moves the files needed to the public folder, I'm not to sure you can just generate the mailer.

Comment: Yes the best solution until now, (not errors yet) is rails g devise:views devise .. is kind of strange, i know, but is the only way i can pull the views correctly