# How to customize devise reset password template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to use the default template to send reset password mail. I generate devise views and restart the server, but still failed with `undefined method 'edit_password_url'`

reset_password_instruction.html.erb

```
<p><%= t(:hello).capitalize %> <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p><%= t '.request_reset_link_msg' %></p>

<p><%= link_to t('.password_change_link'), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token, config: message['client-config'].to_s, redirect_url: message['redirect-url'].to_s).html_safe %></p>

<p><%= t '.ignore_mail_msg' %></p>
<p><%= t '.no_changes_msg' %></p>
```

What's wrong?

upd routes.rb

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'users', controllers: {
          ...
          passwords: 'devise_overrides/passwords'
      }`

I overrided devise user method `send_reset_password_instructions`

```
def send_reset_password_instructions(opts=nil)
    token = set_reset_password_token

    opts ||= {}

    # fall back to "default" config name
    opts[:client_config] ||= "default"
    url = edit_password_url(self, reset_password_token: token, config: opts['client-config'], redirect_url: opts['redirect-url'] 

    opts[:url] = url


    # This is devise send method
    # send_devise_notification(:reset_password_instructions, token, opts)
    # This is mine
    MyMailer.forgot(opts).deliver_now
    token
  end
```

Comment: Add your routes file and the model for the resource in question (user, for example). None of that will work without devise routes and model config.

Comment: pls, see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262856/3686898) you can change `edit_password_url` to `edit_password_path` and pass it the necessary data. Let me know if this has helped.

If not, please provide more information such as which version of Devise you're using, how your controller looks and what the routes' output is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the routes, add to your `router.rb` devise routes:

```
devise_for :users
```

PD: Please show your `routes.rb` in the question.